# Novel (?) proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, radicals, alternative-proof, rationality-testing

A student of mine offered the following proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt{3}$: Suppose $(a/b)^2 = 3$ with $a,b$ having no common factor. Since $a^2=3b^2$, an easy parity argument (using the fact that $a$ and $b$ cannot both be even) shows that $a$ and $b$ must both be odd. Writing $a=2m+1$ and $b=2n+1$ we obtain $(2m+1)^2=3(2n+1)^2$, so $4m^2+4m+1=12n^2+12n+3$. Subtracting $1$ from both sides and dividing by $2,$ we get $2m^2+2m=6n^2+6n+1$, which is impossible since the LHS is even and the RHS is odd.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: I don't know of any formal source, but a colleague recently asked me the same question after a student submitted this exact solution as homework.

Comment: In the title I mentally substituted $\zeta(3)$ for sqrt(3) and was prepared to be astonished...

Comment: This is more or less equivalent to looking at $a^2=3b^2$ mod 4. Abstractly, you could say that this proof deduces the irreducibility of $x^2-3$ over the rationals by showing it over the $2$-adics. That really makes it qualitatively different from the usual descent argument, which works $3$-adically.

Comment: Note that it generalizes very quickly to show that if $k \equiv 3$ (mod 4), then $k^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is irrational.

Comment: @David Conlon: Hmm. I gave this as a homework problem too. Maybe someone with a Chegg or Coursehero account should check to see if the proof is there...

Comment: This has been studied for a while now. The argument fails with 17 rather than 3 and there is a natural question of whether just using parity arguments one can prove the irrationality of $\sqrt 17$. I wrote a thread about it last year. https://twitter.com/AndresECaicedo1/status/1302697810446483456?s=20

Comment: At first I was confused why it was interesting, but now I see it uses only parity arguments, which is indeed interesting. (Though, while novel, is certainly not nearly as illuminating as pretty much any other proof!)

Comment: "Has anyone seen this before?" Yes, 2400 years ago in Theaetetus.

Comment: @SamHopkins Me too, my brain automatically replaced sqrt by zeta.

Comment: [Searching with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(2m%2B1)%5E2%3D3(2n%2B1)%5E2%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csqrt%203%24&p=1) led me to this answer: [Prove that the square root of 3 is irrational](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/930486#930509). (I posted this comment on MO, but it was lost because of the migration.)

Comment: I have seen (somewhere) the comparable proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational by noting that if $a^{2} = 2b^{2}$ for coprime integers $a,b$, then $a^{2} \equiv b^{2} \equiv 1$ (mod $3$), since $a$,$b$ are not both divisible by $3$ (so neither is).

Comment: It comes up in music when explaining why repeated just tempered perfect fifths (frequency ratio of $\frac{3}{2}$) can never be an exact number of octaves (frequency ratio a power of $2$).