# Why is root three an irrational number?

Tags: irrational-numbers

Why is $\sqrt{3}$ an irrational number since it can be expressed as ratio of two numbers $(2\sqrt{3}+3)$ and $(2+\sqrt{3})$ ?

Comment: Where do you not understand?

Comment: A rational number is a ratio of two **integers**. Neither $2\sqrt{3} + 3$ nor $2 + \sqrt{3}$ are integers.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to focus on the key issue here (the definition of rationality) as opposed to the actual proof (which is commonplace, straightforward, and available [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930486/prove-that-the-square-root-of-3-is-irrational) anyways).

---

Being rational or irrational is not a matter of being a ratio of ***two numbers***, but instead of ***two integers***.

If it was the former, ***every*** number $x$ would be rational: consider $\frac x 1$.

To prove that $x$ is irrational, you need to show that there exists no pair of ***integers*** $a,b$ such that $x = \frac a b$.

$2\sqrt 3 + 3$ and $2+\sqrt 3$ are not integers.

Answer (score 0):

Square root of 3 is irrational because it can not be expressed as a ratio between two integers but what you are trying is just to express it as a ratio between two real numbers. If you are interested you can use the method of contradiction to prove that square root 3 is irrational number.