# Proving that the square root of 5 is irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, radicals, rationality-testing

> Prove that $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational.

I begin with the identity $(\sqrt{5} + 2 )(\sqrt{5} - 2 ) = 1$.

Then I am told to extract $\sqrt{5}$ from the first or second factor and consider it to be $\frac{m}{n}$ so I should replace it in both sides.

I have $$\frac{m}{n} = (\frac{1}{\frac{m}{n}} + 2) + 2.$$

I am also told to work on the right side until I have a denominator less than $n$ and I have to explain the reasoning.

Then I have to prove this is false by contradiction.

Right now my main problem is I can't get a denominator less than $n$.

Comment: Ok, **what** is the question?

Comment: Did you really mean to write $1/(m/n)+2$ (that is, $(1/(m/n))+2$) or did you mean $1/((m/n) + 2)$?

Answer (score 4):

Consider $\sqrt{15}$ to be rational. Then we can express it into the form $\frac{p}{q}$, where p and q are integers with $gcd(p, q) = 1.$

Now:
$$\frac{p}{q}= \sqrt{15}$$
$$⇒\frac{p^2}{q^2} = 15$$
$$⇒p^2 = 15 q^2$$
$$⇒ 15|p^2$$
$$⇒ 15|p \tag{*}$$

---

Now let $p = 15m$, for some $m ∈ ℕ$ 
$$p= 15m$$
$$⇒p^2 = (15)^2 m^2$$
$$⇒15q^2 = (15^2) m^2 \text { since $p^2 = 15q^2$}$$
$$⇒ 15|q^2$$
$$⇒ 15|q \tag{**}$$

---

Hence, from $(*)$ and $(**)$, leads us to think that our original assumption that the $\gcd = 1$ is wrong. This is a contradiction. Thus, our original statement holds. Hope this helps (:

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: correcting and simplifying your RHS,
$$\frac{m}{n}=\frac{1}{(m/n)+2}+2=\frac{2m+5n}{m+2n}\ ,$$
but there is no way the RHS denominator is less than the LHS denominator.  Try doing something similar but starting with
$$\sqrt5=\frac{1}{\sqrt5-2}-2\ .$$
This will give you a proof that $\sqrt5$ is irrational.

Comment: First, I think he has $$\frac mn=\left(\frac1{\frac mn}+2\right)+2=\frac nm+2+2=\frac{n+4m}m$$ so how did you get your expression? Second, how in the world did you guess the OP wanted to prove $\;\sqrt5\;$ is irrational?!

Comment: Because when op was talking about irrational numbers he mentioned the exercise

Comment: The OP is you, @DanielOrtizCosta ... and you don't mention **at all** what number is to be proved irrational.

Comment: @Timbuc it's true that the OP has$$\frac1{m/n}+2\ ,$$but it should be$$\frac1{\frac mn+2}$$so I "discreetly" corrected it.  And I guessed that the question was about $\sqrt5$ because this is a standard method for proving irrationality of $\sqrt n$, though not as well known as some other methods.  Of course it may well be that my guess was wrong.

Comment: Thanks @David. Somebody else now added the question to the OP.

Comment: @Timbuc ...and I have made the correction more explicit in my answer.  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this, but unfortunately can't get far, how can I infer the denom is less than n?

Comment: What denominator did you get?

Comment: m-2n @David...., although by dividing by m, I can also get 1 - (2n/m)

Comment: By assumption $\frac mn=\sqrt5$, so by doing some simple algebra you should be able to prove that $m-2n>0$ and $m-2n<n$.

Comment: @David by Working with m - 2n I ended up with a new formula n(√5-2), and by using the fact that √5 = 2.*** I can obviously conclude n(√5-2) < n; however, I can't seem to find a more general way to do it without considering √5 = 2.***; can you hint me?

Comment: The inequality $m-2n>0$ is equivalent to $\frac mn>2$, can you see why this is true?

Comment: Definitely, but the problem is how can I prove m-2n is > 0 @David

Comment: m > 2n so if you subtract m - 2n, then it's definitely going to be greater than 0.

Comment: @user125535 thank you

Answer (score 0):

Once again:

Here is a proof of mine
by contradiction that
if $n$ is a positive integer
that is not a perfect square
then
$\sqrt{n}$ is irrational:
[$\sqrt{17}$ is irrational: the Well-ordering Principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471648/sqrt17-is-irrational-the-well-ordering-principle/472040#472040)