# Prove that $\sqrt{5n+2}$ is irrational

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, rationality-testing

I'm trying to follow [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/953525/188401) to prove that $\sqrt{5n+2}$ is irrational. So far I understand that the whole proof relies on being able to prove that $(5n+2)|x^2 \implies (5n+2)|x$ (which is why $\sqrt{4}$ doesn't fit, but $\sqrt{7}$ etc. does), this is where I got stuck. Maybe I'm overcomplicating it, so if you have a simpler approach, I'd like to know about it. :)

A related problem I'm trying to wrap my head around is: Prove that $\frac{5n+7}{3n+4}$ is irreducible, i.e. $(5n+7)\wedge(3n+4) = 1$.

Comment: what is $n$ here?

Comment: What is $n\wedge m$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde it's $\gcd(n,m)$ (and $n\lor m$ would be $\operatorname{lcm}(n,m)$)

Comment: Beware that the accepted answer is incorrect (or incomplete). If you wish to learn how to generalize the linked proof to your example then one way is to use the method in my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, one way to say it is irrational is to see that $5n+2$ isn't an integer square for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ (it only finish in $2$ or $7$). The other way you're trying lets you the same ending $(p,q\in \mathbb{Z}, q\neq 0)$:
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{5n+2}=\frac{p}{q}&& \\
5n+2=\frac{p^2}{q^2} &&(1)\\
q^2(5n+2)=p^2 && (2)
\end{align*}

Let 
$$p=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\dots p_t^{\alpha_t}$$ $$q=q_1^{\beta_1}q_2^{\beta_2}\dots q_s^{\beta_s}$$

where $p_i,q_j$ are primes and $\alpha_i,\beta_j$ are positive integers.

From $(1)$, $p^2/q^2$ is an integer (is equal to $5n+2$), so you have that the $q_i$ are certain primes $p_j$. Renaming the prime factors in a way such that $q_i=p_i$, you can let you the fraction (considering that $t>s$)

$$\frac{p^2}{q^2}=\frac{p_1^{2\alpha_1}p_2^{2\alpha_2}\dots p_t^{2\alpha_t}}{q_1^{2\beta_1}q_2^{2\beta_2}\dots q_s^{2\beta_s}}=p_1^{2(\alpha_1-\beta_1)}p_2^{2(\alpha_2-\beta_2)}\dots p_t^{2(\alpha_s-\beta_s)}\dots p_t^{2\alpha_t}=5n+2$$

then this implies that $5n+2$ is a square, but by the original statement, it can't be.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why was downvoted my answer?

Comment: I feel like the "This implies that $5n+2$ is a square" part is the cause for downvotes. This is far from obvious for a person unfamiliar with number theory.

Comment: Perhaps because your proof that $\,\sqrt{5n+2}\not\in \Bbb Q\,$ is either incomplete or incorrect. It's impossible to tell which is the case from what little you wrote. Nor does your answer tell how to do it the way the OP asks, using the linked proof. I explain both in my answer.

Comment: Please tell me if this is correct now.

Comment: @MonsieurGalois an easier way to see that 5n+2 is not an integer square is by seeing $(\frac{2}{5}) = (-1)^{\frac{5^2-1}{8}} = -1$, so 2 is not a quadratic residue modulo 5.

Comment: @bat_of_doom yes, it is shorter, but I wrote this way to make the proof the clearest as possible.

Answer (score 6):

For the second question: $\frac{5n+7}{3n+4}$ is irreducible.

For that is enough to see that if there is a prime $p$ such that

$p|5n+7$ and $p|3n+4$

then

$p|[3(5n+7)-5(3n+4)] \Rightarrow p|1$ what is impossible.

Comment: I explain a linear algebra genesis of the above in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\,\ 5\!:\,\ k^2 \in \{0,\pm1,\pm2\}^2\equiv \{0, \pm 1\},\,$ none $\equiv 2,\ $ i.e. squares $\not\equiv 2\pmod5$

But by the [Rational Root Test,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/658058/242) $ $ if $\,x^2\!-15\,$  has a rational root, it is an integer, contra above.

You can't *directly* use the linked proof because it uses $\,15\mid k^2\,\Rightarrow\, 15\mid k,\,$ which works because $\,15\,$ is *squarefree.* But $\,5n+2\,$ needn't be squarefree, e.g. it's $\,12\,$ for $\,n=2,\,$ and $\,12\mid 6^2\,$ but $\,12\nmid 6.\,$ But we  can always reduce to squarefree radicands: write  $\,5n+2 = kj^2.\,$ Then $\sqrt {5n+2} = j\sqrt k\,$ so $\,\sqrt{5n+1}\,$ is rational iff $\sqrt k\,$ is rational. By above $\,5n+2\,$ is *not* a square so it has squarefree part $\,k>1,\,$ so the linked classical method proves $\sqrt k$ irrational $\,\Rightarrow\sqrt{5n+1} = j\sqrt k\,$ irrational.

---

For the second, note that if $\ d\mid 5n\!+\!7,\, 3n\!+\!4\ $ then

$${\rm mod}\ d\!:\,\ \dfrac{7}5 \equiv -n \equiv \dfrac{4}3 \,\Rightarrow\, 0\equiv 7\cdot 3 - 5\cdot 4\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid 1$$

---

Another way is to use Cramer's rule (or elimination) to solve for $\,n\,$ and $\,1\,$ below

$$ \begin{eqnarray} \ 3\,n\, +\, 4\cdot 1 &=& i\\ \\  5\ n\, +\, \ 7\cdot 1 &\ =\ & j\end{eqnarray}
\quad\Rightarrow\quad \begin{array}\  n \  = \ \ \ \,  7
\,i\, -\, 4\ j \\\\  \color{#c00}{\bf 1}\ =\,  {-5}\ \color{#0a0}i\, +\, 3 \ \color{#0a0}j \end{array} $$

Therefore, by the lower equation in the RHS system: $\ n\mid \color{#c00}{\bf 1}\,\ $ if $\,\ n\mid \color{#0a0}{i,\,j}$

---

**Remark** $\ $ In the same way [we can prove more generally](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1911456/242)

**Theorem**  $\ $ If $\rm\,(x,y)\overset{A}\mapsto (X,Y)\,$ is linear then $\: \rm\gcd(x,y)\mid \gcd(X,Y)\mid \color{#c00}\Delta \gcd(x,y),\ \ \ \color{#c00}{\Delta := {\rm det}\, A}$

e.g. $ $ in OP we have $\,\color{#c00}{\Delta =\bf  1}\,$ so the above yields  $\ \gcd(3n+4,5n+7)\mid\color{#c00}{\bf 1}\cdot\gcd(n,1) = 1$

Comment: Notice that $3^{-1}$ exists mod $d$  since $3$ is coprime to $d$, being coprime to its multiple $\,3n\!+\!4.\,$ Similarly we deduce that  $\,5^{-1}$ exists, so both fractions are well defined.

Answer (score 3):

Since
$$
\{0,1,2,3,4\}\overset{x^2}{\longrightarrow}\{0,1,4\}\pmod{5}\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
2\not\in\{0,1,4\}\pmod{5}\tag{2}
$$
we know that $2$ is not a square mod $5$. That means that
$$
5n+2=x^2\tag{3}
$$
has no solutions with $n,x\in\mathbb{Z}$.

If $\sqrt{5n+2}\in\mathbb{Q}$, then there is some $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ so that
$$
x^2-(5n+2)=0\tag{4}
$$
which implies that $x$ is a rational algebraic integer, therefore, by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/309071), it must be an integer. However, this contradicts that $(3)$ has no integer solutions.

Therefore,
$$
\sqrt{5n+2}\not\in\mathbb{Q}\tag{5}
$$

---

Since
$$
3(5n+7)-5(3n+4)=1\tag{6}
$$
we know that $5n+7$ and $3n+4$ have no common factors.