# There're no $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ which verifies $x^2=12$.

Tags: analysis

**Proposition :** $\nexists{x}\in\mathbb{Q}\;|\;x^2=12$.

**Hypothesis :** We can rewrite $x$ like $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^2$ where $\forall{p}\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\forall{q}\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)$ can't be reduced ($p$ and $q$ can't be both even).

**Demonstration :** We have to reject the hypothesis.
$$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^2=12 \rightarrow \frac{p^2}{q^2}=12 \rightarrow p^2=12q^2.$$
That means that $p^2$ must be even. That can be possible only if $p$ is even too. Therefore, we can rewrite $p$ like $2k$ where $\forall{k}\in\mathbb{Z}$.
$$p^2=(2k)^2=4k^2=12q^2\\k^2=3q^2$$

And there's where I stuck!

Can your help me?

Comment: Hint: you can conclude that $k$ must be a multiple of 3, so $k=3m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $3|k^2\Rightarrow 3|k$.

Comment: Here is a simple proof that if $n$ is not a perfect square, then $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471648/sqrt17-is-irrational-the-well-ordering-principle/472040#472040

Comment: You've got issues with your quantifiers and with your whole hypothesis. Your hypothesis should be : "$x=\frac{p}{q}$ for *some* $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ and *some* $q\in\mathbb{N}$ such that the fraction *is* reduced (if you don't suppose this you won't get the contradiction you are seeking)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now continue,
with 3 instead of two.

Since
$k^2 = 3q^2$,
$k$ must be divisible by $3$.
Writing
$k = 3j$,
$9j^2 = 3q^2$,
or
$3j^2 = q^2$,
so $q$ must
also be divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Even/odd won't help here. Try division by $3$:
$$p^2=12q^2\implies 3\mid p^2\implies 3\mid p\implies (3k)^2=12q^2\implies 3k^2=4q^2\implies 3\mid 4q^2\implies 3\mid q$$

---

There's also an alternative way which makes it very easy to see the problem:

If $\frac pq$ is not an integer, then $\bigl(\frac pq\bigr)^2$ also isn't, so the square root must be an integer if it's rational. But
$$12=2^2\cdot 3=n^2$$
is clearly impossible since $3\mid n^2\implies 9\mid n^2$. This method works for any square root.