# Disproving that $\sqrt{4}$ is irrational with the same logic proving that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational

Tags: real-analysis

I have looked up [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251974/where-does-the-proof-of-sqrt-2-is-irrational-break-down-when-trying-to-prove) regarding this disproof, but I got confused.

If I understood it correctly, the disproof flows like this:

Just like we have shown that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational by contradiction,

'Assuming' that $\sqrt{4}$ is rational,

$\sqrt{4}$ = $\frac{p}{q}$ for $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$

$4$ = $\frac{p^2}{q^2}$

$4 * q^2$ = $p^2$

Here, we claim that $p$ is not necessarily a multiple of 4 since the same condition can be sufficed when p is a multiple of 2.

This, to me, feels like a circular reasoning.

Aren't we agnostic of what $\sqrt{4}$ is at the beginning of this disproof?

Bringing up 2(which is an integer obviously) here seems like implying that we already knew that $2 * 2 = 4$

If so, why do we even need to disprove the proposition at the first place rather than stating that $\sqrt{4} = 2 \in \mathbb{Z}$?

I think I am misinterpreting something here, but I cannot see what that is.

Thanks.

Comment: The question isn't disproving $\sqrt 4$ is irrational.  That's trivial! $\sqrt 4 = 2\in \mathbb Z\subset \mathbb Q$.  The question is *why* does *this* proof for proving $\sqrt 4$ is irrational  when on the surface it appears to be *exactly* like the proof that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational.  The question is a matter of testing our understanding of the *original* proof so we can explain why these two situations are different and one of them is just wrong.  No, we were never agnostic to what $\sqrt 4$ was, and we were never agnostic that $2$ is prime. The issue is *why* it is wrong. not that it is.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for the helpful comment!

Comment: "Aren't we agnostic of what 4–√ is at the beginning of this disproof?" No.  "seems like implying that we already knew that 2∗2=4" We did. "If so, why do we even need to disprove the proposition" We aren't trying to disprove the proposition.  We are trying to find a specific error in the proof.  It's not enough to say "we know it is wrong" (which is obvious).  It's a matter of saying "your reasoning is incorrect *here* because you made *this* mistake", not "well you must have made a mistake *somewhere* because we know it is false".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the linked proof, they are not assuming $4=2\times 2$. Rather, they are assuming

$$4\text{ is even }\Rightarrow\ 2|4\ \Rightarrow\ 2|p^2\ \Rightarrow\ 2|p\Rightarrow p=2r$$

(since $2$ is prime). Of course, in the linked question they **do not** prove that the square root of $4$ is rational, only that the same method for proving $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational cannot work for proving that the $\sqrt{4}$ is irrational. This isn't really a big deal, for many $n$ we wouldn't use this reasoning to show $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational and it shouldn't worry us that it primarily works for $\sqrt{2}$. To show that $\sqrt{4}$ is rational, it suffices to say that

$$2>0\text{ and }2\times 2=4\Rightarrow \sqrt{4}=2\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 3):

The proof that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational works for $2$ because 2 is a prime number. If we know that a number $p$ is prime, then we can show that $\sqrt p$ is irrational.
The proof is given by contradiction as we assume $\sqrt p$ to be rational, that is, equal to $\frac ab$, where a and b are positive integers and co-prime. Then we square both sides to get $p=\frac {a^2}{b^2}$ to get $pb^2=a^2$. Now, we can say that "$p$ divides $a^2$, so $p$ also divides $a$" only when $p$ is prime, which we know it is, as we began with $p$ being a prime(I will not explain why it is so, as I'm assuming you already know the reason for that. Basically, you factorize a number into its prime factors and square that number, and notice that only those prime factors are the prime factors of its square as well). Ultimately we show that a and b have a common factor $p$ and so they are not co-prime. Otherwise, if you don't know whether a number is prime, you can't use the same line of reasoning as we did for $\sqrt 2$. 
 Besides, it is much easier to check rationality of the square root of a number than it is to prove it!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @patha you don't need to thank others for their answers. We are gratetful for the upvotes!